# Migrated to Asset Catalogs for launch images. Simulator shows black screen

Tags: iphone, xcode

Upgrading my project to Xcode5.

I've filled out the launch images asset catalog. However when running in the simulator, my launch images don't show for iPhone retina and retina 4-inch. Just a black screen before loading the app.

I've tried Product > Clean. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Double check the sizes of your images in xassets. I had the same problem and once sizes were right launch displayed. Also make sure name of file that includes @2x was changed before adding it to Xcode not while in Xcode.

My Retina size was 640x1136 and 2x size was 320x568. I got a compiler warning and changed the latter image to 640x960 and launches appeared instead of the black screen.